# Form inside while loop is sending only the 1st row data via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a form inside a while loop which I want to use to update the database using ajax. The problem is that when I am using ID only the 1st data or 1st row data of the form is sent no matter which button I click. When I change the IDs to CLASSES the console shows undefined.

Error in Console when using classes:

> Object { credits: undefined, price: undefined, packId: undefined, type: "savePackage" }

HTML Form:

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
          <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <tr>
              <th>Credits</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <?php while($pack = $package->fetch()){ extract($pack); ?>
              <tr>
                <form method="post" action="">
                  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $cp_id; ?>" class="packId">
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" class="editCredits" value="<?php echo $cp_credits; ?>"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" class="editPrice" value="<?php echo $cp_price; ?>"></td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-fill btn-info savePackage">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-fill btn-danger deletePackage">
                  </td>
                </form>
              </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

AJAX Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".savePackage").click(function() {
    var dataString = {
      credits: $(this).closest('form').find('.editCredits').val(),
      price: $(this).closest('form').find('.editPrice').val(),
      packId: $(this).closest('form').find('.packId').val(),
      type: 'savePackage'
    };
    console.log(dataString);
    var $submit = $(this).parent().find('.savePackage');
    $.confirm({
      title: 'Confirm!',
      content: 'Are you sure you want to add this package?',
      buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //dataType : "json",
            url: "ptc-settings-process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
            beforeSend: function(){
              $submit.val("Please wait...");
            },
            success: function(html){
              $.alert(html);
              $submit.val("Save");
            }
          });
        },
        cancel: function(){}
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

I have used `$(this).closest('form').find('.editCredits').val()` method here but there are multiple other forms on the same page too. Therefore, maybe using form element in `$(this).closest('form')` could be causing a problem.

Comment: Replace input type `submit` to `button`

Comment: would that be all? no other changes? cause that didn't work...

Comment: this should help you. `console.log($(this).closest('form'))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `$(".savePackage").click`, the form you are looking for with `$(this).closest('form')` is not found.

I think that is because you have your form inside the table structure after the `<tr>`.

What you could do is move your form to before the `<table>` definition:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
```

You also have a duplicate class definition `class="form-control" class="editCredits"` in your `<input>`.

You could update that to `class="form-control editCredits"`

Instead of using multiple forms, and find the form you could find the closest `<tr>` and then find the `<td>` with the input and the class.

Your code might then look like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".savePackage").click(function() {
    var dataString = {
      credits: $(this).closest('tr').find('td input.editCredits').val(),
      price: $(this).closest('tr').find('td input.editPrice').val(),
      packId: $(this).closest('tr').find('.packId').val(),
      type: 'savePackage'
    };
    console.log(dataString);
    var $submit = $(this).parent().find('.savePackage');
    $.confirm({
      title: 'Confirm!',
      content: 'Are you sure you want to add this package?',
      buttons: {
        confirm: function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //dataType : "json",
            url: "ptc-settings-process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
            beforeSend: function() {
              $submit.val("Please wait...");
            },
            success: function(html) {
              $.alert(html);
              $submit.val("Save");
            }
          });
        },
        cancel: function() {}
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
    <form method="post" action="">
      <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th>Credits</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <?php while($pack = $package->fetch()){ extract($pack); ?>
        <tr>
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $cp_id; ?>" class="packId">
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control editCredits" value="<?php echo $cp_credits; ?>">
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control editPrice" value="<?php echo $cp_price; ?>"></td>
          <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-fill btn-info savePackage">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-fill btn-danger deletePackage">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1st of all thanks for correcting the duplicate class... How I missed it.. so silly of me.. and secondly, it still doesn't work.. I have placed the form code `<form method="post" action="">` outside the table as you mentioned and changed the class. Now I am not getting undefined but the 1st record is getting submitted. Thirdly, the reason why I had form inside the while loop was to make each form separate for each row. So what do you think should be the issue here?

Comment: @SuperGENScript Aha I see, instead of using multiple forms, and find the form you could find the closest `<tr>` and then find the `<td>` with the input and the class. For example: `$(this).closest('tr').find('td input.editCredits').val()` I have updated the answer.

Comment: and keep the form tag still outside the table?

Comment: thanks.. working now.. however I have kept my form tag inside <tr> to make each form a separate form.. working well.. :)

Comment: It works perfect with both the options i.e., have form field inside the <tr> and outside the table. Both works perfectly the same.

Comment: You could use 1 form tag because you can find the data you are looking for relative to the tr you are in.

Comment: accepted your answer.. and do you think the question deserved a -1?

Comment: You showed the code that you have tried and described your problem so IMHO I think this question is ok.